# Is cryptography restricted by users?

Tags: encryption, internationalization, cryptography, globalization

Can anyone tell me whether it is legal to have a web application with highly encrypted data based in the UK which can be used by users based in any other country worldwide?

I understand that many countries like to monitor their citizens and that there are some examples of encryption causing issues for companies such as RIM and their Blackberry's encryption.

Is it the case that a web application would be exempt from such worries if it is physically based in a country such as the UK, where data may be encrypted to any level, or will it have to conform to the rules of whatever countries its users are based in?

Comment: IANAL, but AFAIK the only issues are exporting crypto (if you're code is being sold elsewhere) and letting governments see data if they cry loud enough.

Comment: From the recent online poker takedown, the location of your physical machines does not exempt your sevice from laws governing the the users in the country they are in. At least in the specific case of the servers being in Western Canada (Absolutepoker.com), Isle of Man (PokerStars.com), Channel Islands (FullTiltPoker.com), Malta (UltimateBet.com), and user in the United States.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this survey](http://rechten.uvt.nl/koops/cryptolaw/) on cryptographic laws around the world. The section on UK is quite long.

As for RIM, drawing conclusions is a bit hazardous. As [Schneier says](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2010/08/uae_to_ban_blac.html), "this is a weird story" and only small parts of it are publicly known.